# jQuery image pop-ups being hidden by the browser window

Tags: jquery

Evening all,

I've got a bit of an issue with some pop up images. Here's a link to jsFiddle, where I've uploaded the basics for you to have a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/aETbw/37/

The real page contains a lot more space round the edges of the image so the fact that you can't see the top or right of the image in some instances isn't really an issue. The problem is when the bottom of an image appears beyond the bottom of the browser. Is there any way to have the image move up if it extends beyond the browser window/viewport, so that the whole image is visible?

If possible, I'd also like to know how to make the image stay visible if it's moused over after the camera icon.

Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Martin.

Comment: Ideally it'd do something like the drop-down menus on this page do:http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/supposition-test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run a check to see how your image's position compares to the height of the window after it's displayed, and if needed, move it within the bounds of the window. See http://jsfiddle.net/aETbw/40/

Comment: Thanks @aaron! It's almost working- it does something funny when you roll over subsequent images. It starts them at a coordinate higher up the page.

Comment: This is the actual page (I'm not responsible for the design or code, by the way!) with your code on it: http://1047797239.test.prositehosting.co.uk/grants/index.html

Comment: (I've added in a little bit of code to remove the height and width from the img HTML that the CMS generates)

Comment: The issue appears after the window has scrolled, if that's any help.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, Just wondered if you might know how to get the picture to hover 3px above the bottom of the browser window instead of right on it. The images I'm using have a padding of 2px and a border of 1px and it would be nice (though not essential!) to have the border always in view. Cheers, Martin.

Comment: If you want to accommodate for padding and border of your image, instead of `$('#imgPop').height()`, use `$('#imgPop').outerHeight()`.